fixing console monitor resolution when not connected during boot
I experience the following problem,
Using a Dell U2412Mb 1920x1200 monitor, which as of today is a pretty basic and compatible monitor, I use the monitor connected to Dell R640/R740 type of servers, having either RHEL 7.9 or 8.10 installed.  I have one monitor to serve multiple servers, so sometimes a server will not have any monitor connected to it during boot.  There is no graphics card installed, just whatever comes on the mainboard (matrox g200?)
When the monitor is connected (via VGA which the only display method from the motherboard)  when the system is powered on or at the beginning of a reboot process, then everything ends up being fine and console graphics has the expected 1920x1200 resolution.
But if the server is rebooted without the monitor connected, and then you connect the monitor the display resolution will be 1024x768 at the console login screen.  Then when logged in, you can go to Settings-devices and see the display resolution of 1024x768 with no means of changing it to 1920x1200.  Sometimes however, and never when you really need it to happen, the display resolution will automatically snap to 1920x1200.
What causes this, is there a fix?  Where do you go in RHEL-8.10 to mess with graphics settings, since /etc/X11/xorg.conf is no longer... not that I ever knew how to edit that.  Where/how do you mess with graphical display stuff in Linux ?
